How is it possible that this computer can ping the gateway ? they not in the same subnet
I happened to come across something very strange
I configured an IP address and a subnet mask
and intentionally put a different IP address on the gateway
So that this computer does not go online and it does :\
And I just pinged the gateway address from the computer and it worked?
How can it be ? And he's not in his range


The gateway can be out-of-subnet as long as it's on-link. Being "on link", or "local", is decided not by IP addresses but by the underlying Ethernet network, while the IP subnet configuration merely informs the OS about which hosts are local.
(For example, if you have an Ethernet network where all hosts use 10.5.5.0/24 addresses, and you connect a host that has a 10.9.9.x address to the same Ethernet, it'll be outside of your subnet but it's still on-link – it's still possible to send Ethernet frames to it – even if the OS doesn't know that.)
The subnet mask is not the only way to inform the OS about what addresses are local – usually it's possible to define additional "local routes" or "device routes" which achieve the same thing for IP addresses outside your subnet. (Usually that's done by adding a route with an empty gateway address.)
And gateways, by their nature, always have to be local/on-link to the device trying to use them (because the gateway is addressed using MAC addresses and that only works if it's local). So if you configure an out-of-subnet address as your gateway, the OS just assumes that it's local no matter what the subnet mask indicates – it automatically behaves as if you had manually defined a local route for it.

Great way to state what I wrote in my answer. I couldn't explain it as clearly as you did, so +1 from me. :)

You're mistaken how IP ranges, subnets and gateway works.
That it work is to be expected. As long as the Gateway is a valid ip address, it is going to work.
The use of a subnetmask is only so it can't see other computers. It defines how large or small the network itself is.
The gateway address is purely an address that supplies internet. If you create a VPN connection, it too will have a different gateway address that is not in the same scope as your subnet mask.
A VPN will have its subnetmask going to be 255.255.255.255, yet the gateway works.

You're right. This ain't supposed to work... If everything else is configured properly that is.
So check the router: It is possible the ROUTER itself is using a much wider subnet mask (possible as wide as 255.0.0.0, which was the old-school default for the 10...* class-A network).
In that case some stuff might, by accident, still work.
